# Detecting line intersections between MultiPolygon and LineString in Turf.js

Tags: javascript, geojson, turf

I am trying to write a section of JavaScript code that allows a user to analyse a route they have plotted on a map. After the user has finished plotting their route, I want to determine if the route they have plotted crosses over any areas of interest.

To do this I am using the [lineIntersect](https://turfjs.org/docs/#lineIntersect) method in Turf.js which should allow me to pass a `LineString` and `MultiPolygon`.

I have created a Turf.js [MultiPolygon](http://multiPolygon):

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [
          51.50836874890726,
          -0.091989636996398
        ],
        [
          51.50797826040486,
          -0.088994163337176
        ],
        [
          51.507701047593805,
          -0.085230241948645
        ],
```

(the full object had too many characters to post here so I pasted the full output to [CodePen](https://codepen.io/mycodepenusernameiscool/pen/dyGvwEY))

and converted the user's route to a Turf.js [LineString](https://turfjs.org/docs/#lineString):

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        51.50350693825546,
        -0.027165818854444357
      ],
      [
        51.50115610069437,
        -0.041240038776924066
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

However when I pass these two objects to the [lineIntersect](https://turfjs.org/docs/#lineIntersect) method:

```
turf.lineIntersect(myLineString, myMultiPolygon);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: coordinates must contain numbers
    com turf/turf/turf.min.js:1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multipolygon syntax is wrong, there's missing square bracket at the start and at the and of each polygon within multipolygon. For example, start should be like this:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "MultiPolygon",
    "coordinates": [
     [
      [
        [
          51.50836874890726,
          -0.091989636996398
        ],
        [
          51.50797826040486,
          -0.088994163337176
        ],
        [
          51.507701047593805,
          -0.085230241948645
        ],
```